# Find coordinate member of matrix by rows

Tags: matlab, matrix, find, coordinates, rows

I have matrix

```
A = 
    8 0 8 8 1
    0 6 8 1 1
    5 8 1 1 8
```

Here, I want to find coordinate of value "8". So, there should be a coordinate like:

```
row = 1 1 1 2 3 3
col = 1 3 4 3 2 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use MATLAB's find function:

```
[row,col] = find(A==8);
```